# How do I separate the app icon from the launch image in an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

Thanks for the time to look. I have a weird problem. my Launch image (AKA Splash screen) seems to automatically be tied to my App icon. so I cant change one with out changing the other. In other words, when I add a new app icon, it changes the launch image to match.

I am guessing this has something to do with the .plist file, but I cant figure out where to fix it.

Thanks for the time!

Comment: Can you post a picture/text of your Info.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify them differant in plist file. See [here](http://www.kish.in/how-to-add-icon-and-splash-screen-for-ios-application/)

ALSO

Check [Apple's link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html) for default name of different files. You just need to rename with default name and add the image files in your project.

Comment: Sort of fixed... I still cant add the "splash" screen (but I never really wanted to use that to begin with). I chanted the image names to match Apples suggested name "Icon.png" and that resoled the issue (xcode was setting them to "default.png" and thats when it was duplicating. Thanks for the help!